# Using PKCE auth on swagger with an API that accepts bearer auth

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, swagger, auth0

I'm using Auth0 PKCE authentication on my NuxtJs Application which has a backing Dotnet 6 API. I've set up the API to accept a Bearer token as shown below. For ease of use, I wanted to set up my swagger environment to use PKCE auth also which I've done but the token never authenticates successfully to the Dotnet API. The access token I get from the UI and from postman successfully accessed the API because I am getting the access token and sending it as an authorization header. I attempted to also configure my web API to use OAuth2 along with JWT but the OAuth2 code is never getting hit.

I encountered the same issue originally in postman until I added my API Audience for the token to correctly generate but swagger doesn't seem to allow me to provide an audience.

How do I adjust swagger to use the PKCE auth but generate a token that works for the API?

**Swagger setup:**

```
private static void ConfigureSwaggerGen(SwaggerGenOptions options, IConfiguration config)
    {
        options.OperationFilter<SwaggerDefaultValues>();
        options.UseDateOnlyTimeOnlyStringConverters();

        var xmlFile = $"{typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

        options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, apiDesc) => apiDesc.RelativePath != null &&
                                                            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiDesc.GroupName) &&
                                                            apiDesc.RelativePath.Contains($"api/{docName}/"));

        options.ExampleFilters();
        options.TagActionsBy(api => new[]
            {api.GroupName}); 

        var oauthAuthority = config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthAuthority}"] ??
                             config[Constants.OAuthAuthority];

        var securitySchema = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl =
                        new Uri(
                            $"https://{oauthAuthority}/authorize"),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://{oauthAuthority}/oauth/token")
                }
            },
            Description = Constants.SwaggerAuthDescription,
            Name = Constants.SwaggerAuthName
        };

        options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
        options.AddSecurityDefinition(Constants.SwaggerAuthName, securitySchema);
        options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {Id = Constants.SwaggerAuthName, Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme}
                },
                new List<string>()
            }
        });
    }


private static void ConfigureSwaggerUi(SwaggerUIOptions options, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider,
        IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration config)
    {
        options.OAuthAppName("TestApp");
        options.OAuthClientId(config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthClientId}"] ??
                              config[Constants.OAuthClientId]);
        options.OAuthClientSecret(config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthClientSecret}"] ??
                                  config[Constants.OAuthClientSecret]);
        options.OAuthUsePkce();
        options.OAuthScopes("profile", "openid", "api");
        options.EnablePersistAuthorization();
        options.OAuthConfigObject = new OAuthConfigObject
        {
            ClientId = config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthClientId}"] ??
                       config[Constants.OAuthClientId],
            ClientSecret = config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthClientSecret}"] ??
                           config[Constants.OAuthClientSecret],
            AppName = "TestApp",
            Scopes = new List<string> {"profile", "openid", "api"},
            AdditionalQueryStringParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {
                    "audience", config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthAudience}"] ??
                                config[Constants.OAuthAudience]
                }
            },
            UsePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant = true
        };

        if (env.IsProduction()) options.SupportedSubmitMethods();

        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",
                description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
    }
```

**Dotnet Auth Configuration:**

```
private static void ConfigureAuth(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var authority = config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthAuthority}"] ??
                                config[Constants.OAuthAuthority];
                options.Authority = $"https://{authority}";
                options.Audience = config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthAudience}"] ??
                                   config[Constants.OAuthAudience];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthAudience}"] ??
                                    config[Constants.OAuthAudience],
                    ValidIssuer = $"https://{authority}"
                };

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.SecurityToken is not JwtSecurityToken token) return Task.CompletedTask;
                        if (context.Principal?.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", token.RawData));

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            })
            .AddOAuth("Auth0", options =>
            {
                var authority = config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthAuthority}"] ??
                                config[Constants.OAuthAuthority];

                options.ClientId = config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthClientId}"] ??
                                   config[Constants.OAuthClientId];
                options.ClientSecret = config[$"{Constants.ConfigSettings}:{Constants.OAuthClientSecret}"] ??
                                       config[Constants.OAuthClientSecret];
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/auth/loggedin");

                options.AuthorizationEndpoint = $"https://{authority}/authorize";
                options.TokenEndpoint = $"https://{authority}/oauth/token";
                options.UserInformationEndpoint = $"https://{authority}/userinfo";

                options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                {
                    OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                    {
                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                        var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request,
                            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        var user = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        var jUser = JsonSerializer.SerializeToElement(user);

                        context.RunClaimActions(jUser);
                    },
                    OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnTicketReceived = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAccessDenied = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
    }
```

Comment: Please, check if these approachs can help you: [Swagger UI (OpenApi) with Authorization code flow + PKCE using Swashbuckle ASP.NET Core](https://lurumad.github.io/swagger-ui-with-pkce-using-swashbuckle-asp-net-core) and [OAuth PKCE flow for ASP.NET Core with Swagger](https://www.camiloterevinto.com/post/oauth-pkce-flow-for-asp-net-core-with-swagger)

Comment: @AntonioLeonardo. I think I’m pretty much doing what those article describes for the most part. The auth to auth0 is working but the bearer to the API is not.

Comment: I configured to use OAuth2.0 with net core app and Swagger (with possibility to authorize and use API) and made lib that is accessible from nuget, maybe it could be helpful to you: https://github.com/Wissance/Authorization